# python merging nested dictionaries into a new dictionary and update that dictionary without affecting originals

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 and I'm trying to merge two dictionaries of dictionaries into one dictionary. I'm successful, however, when I add a new key/value pair to the new dictionary, it also adds it to both of the original dictionaries. I would like the original dictionaries to remain unchanged.

```
    dict1 = {'key_val_1': {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}}
    dict2 = {'key_val_2': {'d': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6'}}

    dict3 = dict1 | dict2

    for x in dict3:
        dict3[x]['g'] = '7'
```

The above code will append 'g': '7' to all 3 dictionaries and I only want to alter dict3. I have to assume that this is the intended behavior, but for the life of me I can't understand why (or how to get the desired results).

Comment: This might help you https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: Thank you. Deep copy is the answer I need and I didn't know about it until every ones help on Stack Overflow brought it to light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the root of your problem is your assumption that when concatenating the two dictionaries dict1 and dict2 that python makes a copy of the dictionaries before concatenating them.  In fact Python simply creates a new object with pointers to each of the parts.  With this in mind, when you change the contents of a part of dict3 you are in reality changing the underlying dictionaries dict1 and dict2.  To remedy this condition, you need to make copies of the underlying dictionaries before concatenating them or merge them rather than concatenating them.

Using the copy function:

```
from copy import deepcopy
dict3 = deepcopy(dict1) | deepcopy(dict2)
```

Now dict3 contains independent copies of dict1 and dict2

To merge the dicts:

```
from copy import copy
def merge(d1, d2):
    rslt = dict()
    for k in d1.keys():
        rslt[k] = d1[k].copy() #Note still necessary to copy underlying dict
    for k in d2.keys():
        rslt[k] = d2[k].copy()
    return rslt
```

then use:

```
dict3 = merge(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue you are having is because `dict3` consists reference to the sub-dicts in `dict1` and `dict2`. And the `dict` objects are `mutable`. So, when you change a `dict` in one place, it effects all the place where it is referenced. You can verify it by using the `id()` function. Example:

```py
>>> print(id(dict1['key_val_1']))
>>> 140294429633472

>>> print(id(dict3['key_val_1']))
>>> 140294429633472

>>> print(id(dict2['key_val_2']))
>>> 140294429633728

>>> print(id(dict3['key_val_2']))
>>> 140294429633728
```

From above example you can verify that, the sub-dict in `dict1` and `dict2` are referenced in `dict3`. So, when you modify them in `dict3` the orginial dicts are also modified, as `dict` are `mutable`.

So, to solve your issue, you need to make a `deep copy` of each sub-dict before merging them.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are correct, helped me out with the problem that I was having and helped me understand more how it works (behind the scenes).